# Is (def m (update-in m ks f & args)) a good practice?

Tags: clojure, update-in

I'm new to the world of clojure and I have a doubt.
I have a nested map such as

```
(def accounts (hash-map :XYZ (hash-map :balance (hash-map 171000 0 :171018 500 :171025 200)
                                   :statement (hash-map :171018 [{:desc "purchase" :amount 200}
                                                                 {:desc "deposit" :amount 700}]
                                                        :171025 [{:desc "purchase" :amount 300}]))
```

And I want to update the statements, so I wrote a simple function:

```
(defn add-statement
[account date desc amount]
(def accounts (update-in accounts [account :statement date] conj {:desc desc :amount amount}))
```

But I have a feeling that I'm doing that the wrong way...

Comment: you can use {} instead of hash-map such as: {:XYZ {:balance ....}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change `accounts` to be mutable if you want to update them. The usual way to do this is by making accounts an `atom`. Then your function might look like this:

```
(defn add-statement! [account date desc amount]
  (swap! accounts update-in [account :statement date]
         (fn [line-items] 
           (conj (or line-items []) {:desc desc :amount amount}))))
```

This will add a statement line-item at a new or an existing date. The `update-in` is the same as yours, except that a line-item for a new date will be put into a vector rather than a list. (`conj` keeps the type, but it has to know the type: `(conj nil :a)` gives `(:a)`).

To turn accounts into an atom:

```
(def accounts (atom (hash-map ...)))
```

I notice your balances are not correct anyway. But if you are updating them be sure to do so in the same `swap!` function.

To answer your question, "Is `(def m (update-in m ...))` a good practice?". Definitely not inside a `defn`. If you are thinking to put a `def` inside a `defn` use a `let` instead. Outside of a `defn` it would be fine to have a `def` that updates another `def` that has a different name, so `(def m2 (update-in m1 ...))`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer. That's my first try, I was thinking about using ref (to make transaction and update several accounts at the same time) in a second try